# Como realizar teste com RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Mesmo estudando TDD com RSpec ainda tenho dificuldades para entender como realizar determinados teste.

Como eu faria para realizar um teste para este método que tem um retorno de artigos?

OBS:

1. Utilizo o MongoDB com o ORM mongoID.
2. Neste caso, é realmente necessário realizar o teste?

```ruby
class HomeController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @articles = Article.all
   end
end
```

Comment: Depende. O que você **espera** que esse método retorne? O que é um artigo dentro do seu sistema?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer um teste que criado um determinado artigo no banco de dados, o retorno NÃO deve ser nulo ou o inverso. Existem várias formas de testar isso.

Sugiro que você dê uma lida [neste post](http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html).

Vai te ajudar bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de criar o teste, se você utiliza TDD (Test Driven Development), você tem que saber o que a sua implementação, no caso a action index do seu controller, vai retornar.

No seu caso, ele retorna um array com todos os artigos, portanto, você pode criar um assigns que irá simular sua variável de instância:

Para criar os artigos no ambiente de desenvolvimento, utilize um before each, de preferência com alguma gem tipo o Factory Girl:

```
Rspec.describe ArticlesController do
  before :each do
    @article1 = Article.create(name: 'foo')
    @article2 = Article.create(name: 'bar')
  end

  describe '#index' do
    it 'return an array of articles' do
      assigns(:articles).should eq([@article1, @article2]).
    end
  end
end
```